# Remove vertices until no edges are left

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

Given an undirected graph G(V,E), find the minimum number of vertices to remove so that the Edge Set of the graph becomes empty.

In other words: If we remove one vertex we remove that vertex along with all edges connected to that vertex. Find the minimum number of vertices to remove so that there are no edges left in G after their removal.

Comment: Ya. Actually I searched a little more. I think it's the NP problem. Vertex cover.

Comment: A graph is usually equipped with a $\text{G.adj()}$ operation that, for a given vertex, returns the set of its adjacent vertices; for a generic vertex $v$ let $n_v = \left | \text{G.adj(v)} \right |$. Won't sorting according to $n_v$ and deleting until the exhaustion of edges yield an optimal solution?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Tried this.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure you did post all relevant details in your question? I can't see why the solution I proposed is ineffective.

Comment: @Acsor What's funny is that this problem is NP-complete even on _cubic graphs_, i.e. graphs where _every vertex has degree 3_.  Many problems remain hard on so-called _regular graphs_ (all vertices have the same degree), which shows why that heuristic is very often not so much help.

Comment: @Acsor For a counter-example, consider $P_5$, the path on five vertices.  Since the three internal vertices have degree 2, it shouldn't matter which one you pick, but the unique optimal solution does not pick the middle vertex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you found the answer yourself, you are describing [Vertex Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover_problem), which in many ways are very similar to Independent Set, both problems are [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

The relation to Independent Set is that in a graph $G = (V,E)$, a set $S$ is a minimal vertex cover if and only if $V \setminus S$ is a maximal independent set.

If you know that Independent Set is NP-complete, then it follows that Vertex Cover is NP-complete too.

In other words, you are also looking for a maximum Independent Set.

**Vertex cover**.  Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k$, does there exist a set $S \subseteq V$ of size at most $k$ such that all edges in $G$ are incident to a vertex in $S$?

**Independent set**.    Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k$, does there exist a set $S \subseteq V$ of size at least $k$ such that the *induced graph* $G[S]$ has no edges?